# Pattern in product of primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, pattern-recognition

Let $p_n$ denote the $n$th prime i.e. $p_1 = 2, p_2 = 3, p_3 = 5 ....$ Can we find a pattern in the finite sequence $a_m = \prod_{j=1~j\neq i}^{k}{p_{j}} ~~( \text{mod} ~p)$ for a fixed $j$ and some finite $k$?

For example, let $j =3$ and $k = 10.$ Then $$2 (\text{mod 5}) =2$$
$$2\cdot3 (\text{mod 5}) =1$$
$$2\cdot3\cdot7 (\text{mod 5}) =2$$
$$2\cdot3\cdot7\cdot11 (\text{mod 5}) =2$$
$$2\cdot3\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13 (\text{mod 5}) =1$$
$$2\cdot3\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot17 (\text{mod 5}) =2$$
$$2\cdot3\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot17\cdot19 (\text{mod 5}) =3$$
$$2\cdot3\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot17\cdot19\cdot23 (\text{mod 5}) =4$$
$$2\cdot3\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot17\cdot19\cdot23\cdot29 (\text{mod 5}) =1$$

The sequence $a_n$ is $2,1,2,2,1,2,3,4,1...$
Is there any pattern?

Comment: Why would you think there is a pattern?

Comment: @SarthakGupta As far as I know, there's no known pattern, for any fixed prime, in the modulo values of the primes themselves, much less in their product. When you ask if there's "any pattern", if you mean some form of closed form expression, I'm quite certain the answer is no. However, I can't prove it. If you try some other cases yourself and think you see a pattern, please do some more checking first and, if it still holds and you can't prove it, then you should consider asking here about it. Thanks.

Comment: Working modulo 3, you can compare it to [this sequence](https://oeis.org/A264840) which looks similar.

Comment: All primes greater than $3$ have the form $6m\pm 1$. If there were going to be a pattern to your sequence $a_n$, I would guess that would imply a pattern in the occurrence of primes as either $6m-1$ or $6m+1$. But no such pattern exists, so I doubt (gut feeling) your sequence $a_n$ will ever show a pattern.

Comment: For such a pattern, the prime numbers modulo a given prime would have to exhibit a pattern. As far as I know, such a pattern is not known and very unlikely to exist.

Comment: @Keith Backman sieve of sundaram like reccurence shows 6(6ab+a+b)+1, 6(6ab-a-b)+1, and 6(6ab-a+b)-1 are all the composites in those sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Closest you'll get is $-2ab-a-b+2 \bmod 5$ That's from the sieve of sundaram. After about the fifth round $a$ and $b$ will take on a similar form.  Not much else to say. at least That's the form of this sequence.